# Why is the following algorithm O(1) space?

Tags: python, algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, space-complexity

Input: A list of positive integers where one entry occurs exactly once, and all other entries occur exactly twice (for example [1,3,2,5,3,4,1,2,4])

Output: The unique entry (5 in the above example)

The following algorithm is supposed to be O(m) time and O(1) space where m is the size of the list.

```
def get_unique(intlist):
    unique_val = 0
    for int in intlist:
        unique_val ^= int
    return unique_val
```

My analysis:  Given a list of length m there will be (m + 1)/2 unique positive integers in the input list, so that the smallest possible maximum integer in the list will be (m+1)/2.  If we assume this best case, then when taking an XOR sum the variable unique_val will require ceiling(log((m+1)/2)) bits in memory, so I thought the space complexity should be at least O(log(m)).

Comment: It's O(1) in space because it only uses a single variable `unique_val` (which is a scalar, rather than a list, tuple etc), regardless of the size of the input list.

Comment: It's O(log(m)) if you model memory cells as bits or bytes, and O(1) if you model memory cells as containing arbitrary sized integers. Both models are used in complexity analysis (as are others), but the fundamentals of complexity analysis are not as clean as you might think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis is certainly one correct answer, particularly in a language like Python which gracefully handles arbitrarily large numbers.

It's important to be clear about what you're trying to measure when thinking about space and time complexity. A reasonable assumption might be that the size of an integer is constant (e.g. you're using 64-bit integers). In that case, the space complexity is certainly O(1), but the time complexity is still O(m).

Now, you could also argue that using a fixed-size integer means you have a constant upper-bound on the size of `m`, so perhaps the time complexity is also O(1). But in most cases where you need to analyze the running time of this sort of algorithm, you're probably very interested in the difference between a list of length 10 and one of length 1 billion.

I'd say it's important to clarify and state your assumptions when analyzing space- and time-complexity. In this case, I would assume we have a fixed size integer and a value of `m` much smaller than the maximum integer value. In that case, O(1) space and O(m) time are probably the best answers.

**EDIT (based on discussion in other answers)**

Since all `m` gives you is a *lower-bound* no the maximum value in the list, you really can't provide a worst-case estimate of the space. I.e. a number in the list can be arbitrarily large. To have any reasonable answer as to the space complexity of this algorithm, you *need* to make some assumption about the maximum size of the input values.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was confused about.  The problem statement/solution seemed to tell me I could get O(1) space on an arbitrary list, but then the storage size would be growing as O(logm).  So in the case I can cap the size of an input I would agree on O(1) space, but then as you said the length of the list is bounded and it seems like we get O(1) time too.  I'm still confused on how we could simultaneously have O(m) time and O(1) space.

Comment: One correction: "but then the storage size would be growing as O(logm)". This isn't actually true. The storage size is dependent on the largest value in the list. The size of the list gives a *lower-bound* on this value, but it doesn't give an upper-bound. If your list is just [2^64-1], even though there's only one element, the required space is 64 bits. If you then add a million more 64-bit integers, your required space is still 64 bits. Really, you could say the space complexity is O(log(n)) where *n* is the maximum value in the list.

Answer (score 2):

The (space/time) complexity analysis is usually applied to algorithms on a higher level. While you can drop down to specific language implementation level, it may not be useful in all cases.

Your analysis is both right and possibly wrong. It's right for current cpython implementation where integers do not have a maximum value. It's ok if all your integers are relatively small and fit into the implementation-specific case of small numbers.

But it doesn't have to be valid for all other implementations of python. For example, you could have an optimizing implementation which figures out that `intlist` is not used again and instead of using `unique_val`, it reuses the space of the consumed list elements. (basically transforming this function into a space-optimized reduce call)

Then again, can we even talk about space complexity in a GC'd language with allocated integers? Your analysis of the complexity is wrong, because `a ^= b` will allocate new memory for big value `b` and the size of that depends on the system, architecture, python version, and luck.

Your original question is however "Why is the following algorithm O(1) space?". If you look at the algorithm itself and assume you have some arbitrary maximum integer limits, or your language can represent any number in a limited space, then the answer is yes. The algorithm itself with those conditions uses constant space.

Comment: By the problem statement the length m implies there is a value of at least size (m+1)/2 in it.

Comment: I was thinking that it is at least as bad as O(logm) space if my analysis was right, so that O(1) space could not be an upper bound.

Comment: I'm also unconvinced by myself, I still haven't quite understood what's going on :)  The answers are helping a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of an algorithm is always dependent on the machine model (= platform) you use. E.g. we often say that multiplying and dividing IEEE floating point numbers is of run-time complexity O(1) - which is not always the case (e.g. on an 8086 processor without FPU).

For the above algorithm, the space complexity O(1) only holds as long as your input list has no element > 2147483647 (= sys.maxint). Usually, python stores integers as signed 32 bit values. For those datatypes, your processor has all relevant operations already implemented in hardware and it generally takes only a constant number of clock cycles (in most cases only one) to perform them (= run-time complexity O(1)) and only a constant number of memory addresses (only one) is occupied to store the result (= space complexity O(1)).

However, if your input exceeds 2147483647, python generally uses a software-implemented datatype to store these big integers. Operations on these are no longer in O(1) and they require more than constant O(1) space.